# html div expansion

Tags: java, html

In my project I need to expand my div section,when link is clicked,say "see more".

how can this be done?

Check the one which is in www.facebook.com,where each post has see more,if the div section cant contain the section...

This is the screenshot of what i have done
[image]

Code:

```
<div id="page" >
    <div id="page-bgtop">
        <div id="page-bgbtm">
            <div id="content" style="min-height:400px" >
                <div class="post" >
                    <h2 class="title"><a href="#">UPDATES</a></h2>
                    <%

                    try{
                         st1=con1.createStatement();
                         ResultSet rs=st1.executeQuery("select * from article ORDER BY artid DESC");

                          %>
                          <div style="width:450px; word-wrap: break-word;">
                          <%
                          while(rs.next())
                         {
                         String  s=rs.getString("article");
                         out.println("<div>");
                         out.println("<p align ='justify' >"+s+"</p>");
                         out.println("<hr style='border:dashed #FFFFFF; border-width:1px 0 0 0; height:0;line-height:0px;font-size:0;margin:0;padding:0;'>");
                         out.println("</div>");
                         }
                          %>
                          </div>
                          <% 


                    }catch(Exception e){
                        //System.out.println("exception is "+e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }





                    %>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a javascript function to onclick event of the link. In that javascript function, set the display property of the relevant div to `display:hidden` or `display:block`.

Or

You can set a initial height using CSS height property and set `overflow-y:hidden`
Then `onclick` of the relevant link, change the height of the div to see all of the content.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to expose/hide divs using the [.show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [.hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) methods from JQuery as shown [here](http://designgala.com/how-to-expand-collapse-toggle-div-layer-using-jquery/).